# Center Avatar inside Toolbar with MaterialUI

Tags: center, toolbar, material-ui, avatar

Is there any way to center Avatar component inside Toolbar with MaterialUI components?

```
<Toolbar>
    <ToolbarGroup float="right" lastChild>
        <ToolbarTitle text="Toolbar"/>
        <Avatar src="images/avatar.jpg"/>
    </ToolbarGroup>
</Toolbar>
```

I have been playing with this few hours without any success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean vertical-alignment or horizontal? Anywho you can use the `style` attributes to override the default styles.

```
 <Toolbar>
    <ToolbarGroup float="right" lastChild={true}>
        <ToolbarTitle text="Toolbar" />
        <Avatar src="images/uxceo-128.jpg" style={{alignSelf: 'center'}} />
    </ToolbarGroup>
  </Toolbar>
```

I'm using flexbox css properties on the Avatar to align the avatar vertically. The `Toolbar` has been redesigned recently using `flexbox` in the `material-ui` library.

So you can use flexbox properties to align contents within the `Toolbar` and `ToolbarGroup`.

Hope this helps.