# Material-UI Typography doesn't center in AppBar

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying center the text in an AppBar. I've tried centering the text in Typography element, using align="center", textAlign="center", and style={{ align: "center" }}, among others:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              color="inherit"
              style={{ align: "center" }}
            >
              Header
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

... but is doesn't work unless I remove the Toolbar. But then I would have to manually change the height of the AppBar, which I've also not found a way to do. In addition, every instance I've seen of the AppBar uses the Toolbar. All the solutions that I've found that could address this are [outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732158/react-material-ui-centering-items-on-toolbar) and [don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828967/center-avatar-inside-toolbar-with-materialui) (there's no such thing as a ToolbarGroup anymore).

I've also tried using a const styles and exporting the AppBar withStyles():

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  typography: {
    align: "center"
  }
};

function Header(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            color="inherit"
            className={classes.typography}
          >
            Header
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

Header.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Header);
```

but it also doesn't work. I'm thinking this should be simple, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: `Container` around `Toolbar` will work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [AppBar component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v3.5.1/packages/material-ui/src/AppBar/AppBar.js#L17) is styled to render its children as flex items.

CSS property like [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) is used for horizontal alignment of children that is displayed different from a flex item e.g. as a table cell, block or inline-block.

Flex items can be centered horizontally using the [`justify-content` or `align-self` CSS Property or more other ones](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  appbar: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
};

function Header(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar
        className={classes.appbar}
        color="default"
        position="static"
      >
        <!--...-->
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  typography: {
flexGrow: 1,
    align: "center"
  }
};

function Header(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            color="inherit"
            className={classes.typography}
          >
            Header
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

Header.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Header);
```

use flexGrow,
will do the trick and is responsive in mobile also

Comment: `textAlign: 'center'` instead of `align: 'center'` worked for me. Added a padding on the right same width as my hamburger menu. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following helped me center my title on mobile:

```
<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
    <Box style={{ width: '40px', height: '40px' }}></Box>
</Box>
```